# Why would Software Updater want to update software that is not installed on this box?

Tags: apt

Software Updater wants to update Samba

apt list says that Samba is not installed.

```
$ apt list --installed samba
samba: Installed: (none) 
...
```

Why does Software Updater want to install a package that is not installed?

Answer (score 1):

*All credit to Charles Green for this answer*

Although I do not have Samba explicitly installed, I have another package installed that includes Samba.

This can be demonstrated using

```
$ apt list --installed "*samba*"
```

Or

```
$ apt-cache rdepends samba | grep "  "|xargs apt list --installed
```

And there is a security update available for Samba, so Software Update wants to update Samba.